# Cannot set defaultValue in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using React-Select library in my react project, i am stuck on a point  where i want to set default value on the first select option rendered in a loop.

Here is the code below for your understanding

```
export default function FormSection() {
  const options = [
    { value: "Titular", label: "Titular", isDisabled: true },
    { value: "Conjuge", label: "Conjuge" },
    { value: "Filho(a)", label: "Filho(a)" },
  ];

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      relation: null,
    },

    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    },
  });

  const calcFormikValuesSelect = (index) => {
    if (formik.values.relation == null) {
      return null;
    } else if (formik.values.relation) {
      let allrelation = formik.values.relation;
      return allrelation[index];
    }
  };
  const handleChangeRelation = (selectedOption, index) => {
    console.log(selectedOption, index);
    formik.setFieldValue(`relation[${index}]`, selectedOption);
    // formik.setFieldValue('firstSmoker', selectedOption)
  };

  return (
    <div className="secondSection">
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        {Array.apply(null, { length: 3 }).map((item, index) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="wrapper-person-2">
              <p className="tab-text">Profissão</p>
              <Select
                value={calcFormikValuesSelect(index)}
                name={`relation[${index}]`}
                onChange={(selectedOption) =>
                  handleChangeRelation(selectedOption, index)
                }
                options={options}
                className="select-smoker"
              />
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}

        <button type="submit" className="button-enabled">
          CONTINUE
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So for index=0, i want to set default value

> {value:'Titular,label:'Titular}

and disabled that Select so that dropdown does not show on click and then for index above 0 I want to show the options as options array has

I tried passing prop to React-Select like

> defaultValue:{label:'Titular',value:'Titular}

but that doesn't work

> "react-select": "^4.3.1",

Hope someone helps me out, thanks !

Comment: Is it a multiselect?

Comment: nope @ManishJangir

Answer (score 1):

To set the default value in formik, you need to provide it in `initialValues` like this:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      relation: {0: options[0] } OR [options[0]], // depends on how you put it
    },

    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    },
});
```